# n68 s-ucc front panel audio

Tags: windows, audio

I have a motherboard asrock n68 s-ucc, and i need a hand identifying which pins on the board to connect my front audio header connectors to.

On the connectors I have:

double connector: GND and MIC IN 
 double connector: LINE OUT FL and LINE OUT RL 
 double connector: LINE OUT FR and LINE OUT RR 
 simple connector: MIC POWER

On the motherboard I have:

GND 
 PRESENCE# 
 MIC_RET 
 OUT_RET 
 MIC2_L 
 MIC2_R 
 OUT2_R 
 J_SENSE 
 OUT2_L

manual of motherboard
 [image]
 [image]

and my front panel

[image]
 Thanks so much to all

Comment: some images might help - is your front panel connectors a loose bundle of cables? I've seen this before, but thats always alongside an AC97 or intel HDA header - mine looked like that http://superuser.com/questions/419038/hd-audio-or-ac97-connector-which-to-use-when-and-whats-the-difference but I have also seen a 3 headed version.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek  here add image

Comment: o0 I've NEVER seen anything like that 'front panel' before. I do think thats the loose bundle of connectors I mentioned in the comments to the other question