# 5.1 3.5mm speakers into motherboard with stereo 3.5mm input

Tags: audio, motherboard, sound-card

I have an Intel DQ670W motherboard, with

```
 1 x Stereo Out
 1 x Microphone In
 1 x Line In
```

3.5mm on the rear panel, with Stereo and Microphone repeated on the front panel.

I have some Logitech 5.1 speakers, all 3.5mm, so

```
 1 x Front
 1 x Rear
 1 x Sub / Center
```

Clearly, in traditional analog, I can only plug the front speakers in.

I am wondering if there is a way use these speakers with some sort of inbetween connection.  I was looking at USB to 5.1 but really, the USB stick is an actual sound card, and I want to use the sound card on-board.

I see that the motherboard has AC97 headers and HD Audio headers.  I am not what this means, where one should be used in place of another.  What is the difference?

This http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dq67ow.html says that there are three audio output channels, which makes me wonder if the back panel inputs can be changed to outputs.

Can they?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is.  "the back panel inputs can be changed to outputs." - They already are.  There is no such thing as `Microphone Out`

Comment: Install the Realtek drivers and utilities for the audio and it should ask you "What did you just plug in?", or something to that effect. :)

Comment: My most of my systems tend to have 6 outputs specifically to handle that. I do suspect that trying the drivers is your first port of call, then consider the external sound card. I also have heard of some  5.1 speakers taking SPDIF directly... so... what kind of speakers? Oh and http://superuser.com/questions/419038/hd-audio-or-ac97-connector-which-to-use-when-and-whats-the-difference may be of interest

Comment: @techie007 As I was writing this, I figured I should check just that, but wasn't able to at the time.  Of course, you are right, and I should have figured this out after having done similar things by hand with linux.  You are welcome to add this as an answer.