# Dont know where to connect HD AUDIO or AC-97, & USB

Tags: motherboard, connector

I'll provide pictures so you guys can see,  but basically I recently bought a new case for my pre built [Lenovo k330b](http://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/ideacentre-k-series-desktops/ideacentre-k330b?c=1). I cannot find how I'm supposed to position the connectors.

Do I need to get an entirely new motherboard?
Is there any adapter I can buy?

Any help is welcome.

[image: Motherboard]
[image: Connectors]

Comment: motherboard manual should tell you where everything goes...

Answer (score 1):

You need these Lenovo Motherboard to Standard ATX Case Adapter Cables (3 Types)

https://www.moddiy.com/products/IBM-Lenovo-Motherboard-14-Pin-to-Standard-ATX-Case-Adapter-Cable-30cm.html

https://www.moddiy.com/products/IBM-Lenovo-Motherboard-13-Pin-to-Standard-9-Pin-HD-Audio-Adapter-Cable.html

https://www.moddiy.com/products/IBM-Lenovo-Motherboard-11-Pin-to-Standard-9-Pin-USB-Adapter-Cable.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by digging up a manual - [I had a very similar question in the past](https://superuser.com/questions/419038/hd-audio-or-ac97-connector-which-to-use-when-and-whats-the-difference?rq=1)

You use HD audio on the orange port, USB2.0 on either one of the yellow ones. They look about standard to me. AC97 is super rare these days.

Weirdly, your USB3.0 port is not populated, and that would use a connector styled similar to an old school PATA plug anyway.

Comment: Maybe it is the picture, but the audio pins on the board look fully populated...it should have a missing one for the keyed header from the cases front panel...right? It just looks weird. I think that is what is confusing the OP - all the pins on the mobo, though marked, are not matching the headers pin count from the cases front panel headers.

Comment: Maybe. Might be a good idea to get a picture from the original case plug...

Comment: @CarlB its the picture,  all the ports have a key on them.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fjipy11ccpqdpb/20141030_062622.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The connector looks non standard to me- the 'blank' pin looks like its the wrong place for either..

Comment: @AngeloCassinelli - I meant the pins on the board. The plugs look right, but there is no blank pin on the board to key the plugs.

Comment: @CarlB The picture doesn't illustrate it very well, the motherboard is a CIH61M

Answer (score 0):

3pcs Suitable for Lenovo motherboards with ordinary chassis transfer wiring switch cable USB cable audio cable three-piece set
https://a.aliexpress.com/_mOiyT40

This is all you need. Around 3 dollars for 3 pieces from a trustworthy china shop. Free shipping. If link is dead, similar stuff can be found for similar price, just look around, normally amazon & ebay are gonna be pricey.