# Old PC case, new motherboard, connector incompatibility

Tags: usb, audio, motherboard, case, pin

I have an old PC desktop case, about from the ddr1 / single core k7 era.

I've modernized it into a much newer desktop machine (centralized around an MSI 970A motherboard, if it matters).

Everything goes well, with a single exception: there are some connectors in the case, which can't be plugged into anywhere on the motherboard. The common hddled, powerled, reset and powersw pins have their place, but these on the images haven't.

Here are the pictures for the not working connectors. They are:

- An analog sound input and output
- And two usb connectors (on the motherboard, there are only like [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aE2y30bIejE/maxresdefault.jpg))

I think, maybe some type of converter could (should) exist which makes it possible to plug these connectors into the mainboard. What is it?

P.s. I am asking *not* for product, I am asking for a *name* of the needed devices, or for a *solution* for the problem.

P.s.2. The trivial "Buy a new case for $5" *is* *not* an acceptable answer.

P.s.3. "There are probably *no* converters for this" *is* an acceptable answer.

P.s.4. Reacting the comments about the bad image quality: I tried to fix the first image, and substituted the other two with analogous images from the net. I hope it is now acceptable, if not I am ready to make it yet better. Unfortunately, I don't have physical access to the named machine any more, so I can't make better photos.

[image: USB+, USB-, Vcc, GND]
[image: MIC, SPKR L/R, GND]
[image: Connector not working]

Comment: The connectors from the top picture look like standard USB2. And your motherboard has three connectors marked J_USB1, J_USB2 and J_USB3. If I looked at the correct manual (http://www.msi.com/product/motherboard/support/970A-G46.html#down-manual) then should just be able to plug these into the MB. No answer on the other plugs though.

Comment: Careful connecting usb to mobo header pins, it does not look line they match the standard usb header (as far as order), which is common on oem mobo's, you may have to remove each wire from the connector and attach to usb pins on mobo, do your research. Do it wrong and it will kill that usb connection on the mobo for good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh god what a pain in the *rear*

So... here's what you need to do.

Look up the pin out for USB 2.0 and figure out which connector goes where. It'll just work.

I believe this is the correct pinout

[image]

Audio gets a bit tricky. They've actually switched between different standards and they're not really compatible. If your motherboard lets you select between AC97 and HDA compatibility you could look up the pinout and connect them as needed. [Wikipedia talks about it in detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_High_Definition_Audio#Front_panel_connector) as does the answer to my [old question](https://superuser.com/questions/419038/hd-audio-or-ac97-connector-which-to-use-when-and-whats-the-difference). I'd try matching up the connectors with the pin outs and see what happens. It might not work quite right without the motherboard/sound-codec being aware of AC97 though

If you could find something that goes from female HDA to male AC97 or a replacement for the whole front panel unit or maybe even a drive bay that does audio out, you could get headphone/mic jacks working.

Comment: Those USB wires in the photo look "beefy," but is there any reason to be concerned about wire gauge in this context (I suspect not, but...)?

Comment: Not. If its worked so far, it should work now

Comment: There is a much harder problem: I've found only SPDIF connectors on the motherboard, AC97 / HDA not. But it was not a problem, finally the owner the machine said, if it doesn't work, she can live with it (she is using the the connectors on the back). Your USB idea worked perfectly - I could simply plug the 3pin-connector to the USB+5V/LP-/LP+, and the USB GND to the GND pins.

Answer (score 2):

When all else fails, read the manual. I found the [manual](http://www.msi.com/product/motherboard/support/970A-G46.html#down-manual) on the MSI site and was able to find these pin-outs quickly.

**For the Audio;**

[image]

**For the Front Panel USB connectors;**

[image]

These can easily be connected without replacing the connectors or adapting them.

Comment: That's for azalia/intel HDA. A case that old might be AC97

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember, but yes, probably an AC97 was there. But it had also an SPDIF connector, which is a digital audio format an it was completely unusable in our case.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick read into your MB, you need M-connectors.

You may need to contact MSI and order the correct ones, or flip through the net to find the right M-connector.

Comment: I searched the net a little bit, mainly in the sound case (the USB I could solve), but couldn't find anything. But anyways, thank you very much the googleable name (m-connector)!