# How do I connect the wires to the front panel audio pins?

Tags: audio, motherboard, headers, front-panel

I need some help with plugging the wires to the pins on the motherboard. I have got no idea which wires I should plug to the pins as I am not really sure where the wires goes.

Here is the wires I have got:

```
Ear R+
Ear R-
Mic VDD
Ear Gnd
Mic Gnd
Ear L-
Mic Data
Mic L+
```

Here is the front audio headeder:

```
GND
MIC2_L
PRESTENCE#
MIC2_R
OUT2_R
MIC_RET
J_SENSE
OUT2_L
OUT_RET
```

I guess that this is where I should plug the wires to the pins but I am not really sure:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|               Ear & Mic connection         |
+-----------------------+--------------------+
| M/B layout ASROCK     |    Case layout     |
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
| 1 | GND               | MIC GND            |
| 2 | MIC2_L            | MIC L+             | 
| 3 | PRESTENCE#        | NO PIN             |
| 4 | MIC2_R            | MIC R+             | 
| 5 | OUT2_R            | MIC R-             | 
| 6 | MIC_RET           | NO PIN             | 
| 7 | J_SENSE           | NO PIN             |
| 8 | OUT2_L            | MIC L-             |
| 9 | OUT_RET           | NO PIN             |
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
```

If I am wrong please let me know and which wires I should plug to the correct pins.

The name of the motherboard I have got is: ASRock 980DE3/U3S3 Rev2.0 AM3+ AMD Motherboard.

Comment: Most cases come with a front panel plug that already fits the pins on the motherboard.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Yeah i know but my case are old so it doesn't come with it when I bought a new motherboard. So in my question have I got it right when I point out of what wires goes to what pins on the motherboard?

Comment: I never had to connect the single wires myself, but I don't think you can damage something in this case by guessing wrong.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Oh right so is it possible if you can help me to find which wires goes to which pins for me to plug in?

Comment: If you have an older case, it might use AC97. They are mostly compatible, see https://superuser.com/questions/378082/how-to-connect-my-front-audio-panel

Comment: Use a set of alligator test leads like [these](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12978) to verify the connection points.

Comment: Does anyone know what wires goes to which pins on the motherboard??